# Difference between distributing (distinguishable/indistinguishable) objects into groups

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having a bit of problem doing the following:

1) Number of ways to distribute 7 (different) students in 4 (non empty) teams:

1. $490$
2. $350$
3. $560$
4. $210$

My understanding this is the Stirling number of the second kind and we can use inclusion-exclusion:
$$S(7,4)=\frac{1}{4!}\sum_{j=1}^4(-1)^{4-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n=\frac{1}{24}(-4+768-8748+16384)=\frac{8400}{24}=350.$$

2) Number of ways to distribute 7  tutors into 4 departments where each department must get at least 1 tutor:

1. $350$
2. $4200$
3. $1400$
4. $8400$

I don't quite see the difference here. How does the fact that the "tutors" are not distinguishable affect this?

Comment: In the second question, both the tutors and the departments are distinguishable.

Comment: If they were it would be added to the question I think. Else why would it be added to the first one?

Comment: People are understood to be distinguishable unless otherwise specified. Unless teams are named, they are unlabeled groups.  However, departments have labels.  For instance, the mathematics department is different from the physics department.

Comment: So 1400? 350 x 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are considered to be distinguishable unless otherwise specified.  The difference between the two questions is that departments are distinguishable  while unlabeled teams are not.

> Number of ways to distribute $7$ students to $4$ (nonempty) teams.

Your answer of $S(7, 4) = 350$ is correct since the teams are not labeled.

> Number of ways to assign $7$ tutors to $4$ departments so that each department receives at least one tutor.

Since departments are distinguishable (the mathematics department is different from the physics department), the answer to this question is 
$$4!S(7, 4) = \sum_{k = 0}^{4} (-1)^k \binom{4}{k}(4 - k)^7 = 4^7 - \binom{4}{1}3^7 + \binom{4}{2}2^7 - \binom{4}{3}1^7 + \binom{4}{4}0^7 = 8400$$
where $\binom{4}{k}$ is the number of ways of excluding $k$ of the $4$ departments from receiving a tutor and $(4 - k)^7$ is the number of ways of distributing the $7$ students to the remaining $4 - k$ departments.